# ASP.NET Core: how to save an object into a list which in the controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, controller

My question is how to save an object into a list which in the controller? I'm not using a database for this and I only need this to work as a mock up. This is my code below including the controller and the model which I'm using.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    public List<Article> vijesti = new List<Article>() {
        new Article("1", "naslov", "podnaslov", "duzi tekst"),
        new Article("2", "naslov2", "podnaslov2", "duzi tekst2"),
        new Article("3", "naslov3", "podnaslov3", "duzi tekst3"),

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Article> Get()
    {
        return vijesti;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string InsertArticle ( string id, string naslov, string podnaslov, string text)
    {
        Article article = new Article(id, naslov, podnaslov, text);
        this.vijesti.Add(article);
        return "prosao";
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public void DeleteArticle(string ID)
    {
        this.vijesti.RemoveAll(articles => articles.id == ID);
    }
}

public class Article
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string naslov { get; set; }
    public string podnaslov { get; set; }
    public string tekst { get; set; }

    public Article(string v1, string v2, string v3, string v4)
    {
        this.id = v1;
        this.naslov = v2;
        this.podnaslov = v3;
        this.tekst = v4;
    }
}
```

Comment: you already create a list and you keep in vijesti what is your purpose can you explain more

Comment: So this is just a mock up, I basically want  to do CRUD methods on this list without having a database, I hope this clears it up.

Comment: can you also share view part of code?

Comment: Hi @Zijah,any update about this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `vijesti` to static.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class NewsController : ControllerBase
{
    public static List<Article> vijesti = new List<Article>()
    {
        new Article("1", "naslov", "podnaslov", "duzi tekst"),
        new Article("2", "naslov2", "podnaslov2", "duzi tekst2"),
        new Article("3", "naslov3", "podnaslov3", "duzi tekst3"),
    };
   
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Article> Get()
    {           
        return vijesti;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string InsertArticle(string id, string naslov, string podnaslov, string text)
    {
        Article article = new Article(id, naslov, podnaslov, text);
        vijesti.Add(article);
        return "prosao";
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public List<Article> DeleteArticle(string ID)
    {
        vijesti.RemoveAll(articles => articles.id == ID);
        return vijesti;
    }
}

public class Article
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string naslov { get; set; }
    public string podnaslov { get; set; }
    public string tekst { get; set; }

    public Article(string v1, string v2, string v3, string v4)
    {
        this.id = v1;
        this.naslov = v2;
        this.podnaslov = v3;
        this.tekst = v4;
    }
}
```